# How do I display mysite targeting detail properties on ALL user profiles displaying on person.aspx

Tags: my-site, mysite, mysites

I need to customize SharePoint 2013 person.aspx page layout to display the Location property in the Targeting Details. What's the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, then you need to follow these steps:

1. Go to Central Administration
2. Click on Manage service applications -> Select User Profile Service
3. Click on Manage User Properties
4. Add a new Property and map it with AD field or edit an existing property.
5. Make sure you tick "Show in the profile properties section of the user's profile page" and set "Default Privacy Setting" to "Everyone"